# Matlab ButtonDownFcn not working with image

Tags: matlab, onclick, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, buttonclick

I am trying to zoom-in on areas of the Mandelbrot set using a button press. I am using GUIDE and thus want to use the `ButtonDownFcn` of an axes. I store the image within an array called `imag`, which contains `x` & `y` coordinates and colour.

The function can be called before plotting, however when I display the image using the following commands it is no longer accessible:

```
axes(handles.DrawAxes);
cla

imagesc(imag,'HitTest','Off');
```

Answer (score 0):

[As explained here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100071-why-is-the-buttondownfcn-property-of-an-axes-in-a-gui-not-called-after-i-plot-a-figure-in-matlab-7), [high-level](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html#buryijq) plotting functions actually clear the axes properties when called. So you either use the `hold` function (which affects the `NextPlot` property), or simply set the axes `ButtonDownFcn` callback **after** `image`/`imagesc`/`imshow` are called.

Here is an example:

```
% create axes
ax = axes();

% display image
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
imagesc(img, 'Parent',ax, 'PickableParts','none', 'HitTest','off');
axis(ax, 'image')
colormap gray

% set click callback
ax.ButtonDownFcn = @(o,e) disp('axis clicked');
```

Later if you need to update the image, use the image handle to update `CData` property instead of re-plotting the image.

Comment: Note: example above was written for HG2 graphics system introduced in R2014b. Should be easy to change it for older releases..

Comment: So i can now get the buttondownfnc to work using the following:

axes_handle = handles.DrawAxes;
imagesc(imag,'HitTest','Off');
set(axes_handle, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@FcnName,a,b});

however I am not sure how to get the position clicked or be able to access handles for my GUI.

Comment: those are separate questions, you should create a new question and ask about that part.. But to get you started, there's a `CurrentPoint` property used to retrieve the mouse position. As for the handles, you could either use `findobj` or store the handles in the UI using `guidata` or `getappdata`.